# Integrating groovy in java in gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, gmavenplus

Im trying to integrate groovy in java with build tools as gradle,
There are several examples with maven build, but with gradle its still missing.

I tried of adding plugin of groovy, but for compiler plugin like gmavenplus.
I try to add it as dependency but not sure how i can add it in gradle

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix Java classes into a Groovy project.

1. Create a Groovy project using `gradle init`.
2. Your Groovy source will be in a `source/main/groovy` folder.
3. Add a `source/main/java` folder (but see the comment, below, from Jeff Scott Brown)
4. Add your java files in the java folder, in the usual way.
5. Do the same for your `src/test` folder

### Example src folder structure

```
src
└───main
    ├───resources
    ├───groovy
    │   └───mixedbuildtest
    │           App.groovy
    │
    ├───java
    │   └───mixedbuildtest
    │           JavaApp.java
```

### Example source code

#### Groovy Source Code

```
package mixedbuildtest

class App {
    String getGreeting() {
        return 'Hello from Groovy!'
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        println new App().greeting
        println new JavaApp().greeting
    }
}
```

#### Java Source Code

```java
package mixedbuildtest;

class JavaApp {
    String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello from Java!";
    }
}
```

### Example output

```
F:\projects\sx\MixedBuild>gradle run

> Task :app:run
Hello from Groovy!
Hello from Java!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
F:\projects\sx\MixedBuild>
```

Comment: Be aware that if you use that approach with separate source folders for Java and Groovy that our joint compiler is not going to allow bidirectional dependencies.  You can customize the generated build config to account for that by deviating from the default source sets for the compilation tasks.  More common best practice is to use a single source folder for Java and Groovy.  If that folder is `src/main/groovy`, `src/test/groovy` etc, then the joint compiler will work with the default generated build.